# MYSQL left join not working

Tags: mysql, join

I have three (3) tables:

- `vehicle` table:
  [image: Vehicle table]
- `userCarMapping` table:
  [image: userCarMapping]
- `userInfo` table
  [image: userInfo]

I want to get all vehicles from `vehicle` table and `firstname` and `last name` from `userInfo` table if a vehicle is mapped to a user in `userCarMapping` table.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT `vehicle`.`vehicleId`, `vehicle`.`modelId`, `vehicle`.`RegNo`, `userInfo`.`firstName`, `userInfo`.`lastName` 
FROM `vehicle` 
LEFT JOIN `userCarMapping` ON `vehicle`.`vehicleId` = `userCarMapping`.`vehicleId` 
LEFT JOIN `userInfo` ON `userCarMapping`.`userId` = `userInfo`.`userId` 
WHERE `vendorUserId` = '1' AND `vehicle`.`status` = 'approved' AND `userInfo`.`status` = 'approved'`
```

and I'm getting this output where as I want all the vehicles from `vehicle` table.

[image: output]

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and, [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if they both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: `AND userInfo.status = 'approved'`: this turns your `left join` into an `inner join`. Move this condition to the join condition.

Comment: HINT : Replace `WHERE` by `AND`

Comment: @axiac ok, sorry for that and thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `userinfo` table condition in `where` then it only return those rows which satisfy the condition.But if you use that `userinfo` condition in join instead of where , then table join rows which satisfy the condition like it there is 5 records in `userinfo` table and records with `status active` only two then join consider only this 2 rows for the join.

Try below query:

```
 SELECT `vehicle`.`vehicleId`, `vehicle`.`modelId`, `vehicle`.`RegNo`, `userInfo`.`firstName`, `userInfo`.`lastName` 
 FROM `vehicle` 
 LEFT JOIN `userCarMapping` ON `vehicle`.`vehicleId` = `userCarMapping`.`vehicleId` 
 LEFT JOIN `userInfo` ON `userCarMapping`.`userId` = `userInfo`.`userId`  AND `userInfo`.`status` = 'approved'`
 WHERE `vendorUserId` = '1' AND `vehicle`.`status` = 'approved'
```

Hope you understand the answer.

Comment: your query is working but why mine is not working ? you only had userInfo condition before where. please explain. ???

Comment: @NilkamalGotarne, when you wright that condition in `where` clause that time it consider those records which status is active . And in my case , It only consider those records which status is active for the Join.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue lies in the WHERE of your query.

```
SELECT
    vehicle.vehicleId,
    vehicle.modelId,
    vehicle.RegNo,
    userInfo.firstName,
    userInfo.lastName
FROM
    vehicle
LEFT JOIN userCarMapping ON vehicle.vehicleId=userCarMapping.vehicleId
LEFT JOIN userInfo ON  serCarMapping.userId=userInfo.userId
WHERE vendorUserId= '1' 
AND vehicle.status= 'approved' 
AND userInfo.status= 'approved'
```

Basically, if a user doesn't exist for a vehicle it's still looking for the userInfo table with an **approved**. If you remove

```
AND userInfo.status= 'approved'
```

Do you get the information you want?

Comment: yes after removing `AND userInfo.status= 'approved'` working fine. but then how can i achieve the desired result

Comment: You can simply move the 

AND userInfo.status= 'approved'

to the left join as so

LEFT JOIN userInfo ON  serCarMapping.userId=userInfo.userId 
AND userInfo.status= 'approved'

Basically this says 'Give me the vehicles and the users where their status approved and they line up to a user ID. 

VS

'Give me the vehicles and the users where the user ID lines up WHERE the vehicle and the userInfo status = approved, if a user doesn't like up userInfo.status is equal to NULL so it's excluding those.